# No ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict in Ventura

Tags: keyboard, ventura, customization

For custom Key bindings, "the internet" [macos compose](https://github.com/Granitosaurus/macos-compose), [custom compose key](https://www.alexandergoller.com/journal/14210/compose-key-on-macos/), ... suggests to edit the `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file. I do not have this file on my 13.2.1 Mac OS. Has this been moved/renamed or am I supposed to create it and the system will recognize it (after relaunch?)?

Comment: If it's not here, create it maybe?

Comment: Yes: it doesn't exist by default: you have to create one and put it there.

Comment: wild that no one says this (in their blogs), I will try!